# Matlab if x = 0×1 empty double column vector

Tags: matlab, if-statement, is-empty

What's the correct syntax for

```
if x = 0×1 empty double column vector

x = 5

end
```

I've tried this:

```
if x == [] 

x = 5

end
```

But it doesn't seem to work, and I'm not sure how else to do this.

To put it another way, I get this error message when I try to write x to something: `Unable to perform assignment because the size of the left side is 1-by-1 and the size of the right side is 0-by-1.`, so I'm trying to implement something that just makes x zero rather than empty.

Comment: `if isempty(x)`

Comment: Or, if you really want to check only for that size: `if isequal(size(x), [0 1])`

Comment: That's done the trick, thank you. Do you want to post it as a proper answer that I can upvote and accept? @CrisLuengo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From @crisluengo

if isempty(x)